# publishing a report from pentaho

Tags: reporting, pentaho, business-intelligence

I published a report named stock2.prpt from pentaho report designer on the server .
I'm trying to open my report from pentaho platform  but I get an empty page .
[this is it :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BbAJ.png)

Comment: It works in PRD? you published from PRD or uploaded to Server? any errors?

Comment: yes it works in PRD and I published from PRD without any errors but I can't see it on server pentaho it gives me a blank page .

Comment: you have a ktr attached? Whats the server OS?

Comment: @MohamedAmine Check the log files of the pentaho. I guess you might find some errors reported on the report.

Comment: do you have driver in BA server for data source you used in report designer?